# PrimeFaces FileUpload timeout message

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have a project running on PrimeFaces 5.2 (JSF 2.2). On one of the pages I use the FileUpload part of PrimeFaces, which works quite well except for one case. When the file is being denied by the server firewall or antivirus, the upload bar is stuck in midway and no progress is logged. The end-user can see no message, and the page stucks with no way to progress. The server receives no message for the file upload denial, and so I have no event to catch to print a message.What is the best way to simulate a failed file upload that never reaches the server? I have been thinking that a time-out timer should fire, but since it is an upload and upload speeds vary, this is not always optimal. A "large" file upload (5MB) could take a minute for a client, so the timer cannot be less than a minute, but waiting 1 minute for 5kb is too long. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: The `p:fileupload` has an `onerror` attribute, did you try with that?

Comment: Yes, it does not work, since no error is actually logged/returned.